# Use sudo with password as parameter

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I would like to run sudo with my password as parameter so that I can use it for a script. I tried

```
sudo -S mypassword execute_command
```

but without any success. Any suggestions?

Comment: you should just check if your script is run by "root". It's bad to echoing the password, it will be found in the history...

Comment: It's much better to configure `sudo` properly that it won't ask password for certain program/users/group to avoid such dirty hacks.

Answer (score 244):

The -S switch makes sudo read the password from STDIN. This means you can do

```
echo mypassword | sudo -S command
```

to pass the password to sudo

However, the suggestions by others that do not involve passing the password as part of a command such as checking if the user is root are probably much better ideas for security reasons

Comment: How about putting it in a dedicated folder giving both it and the folder execute-only permissions: `sudo chmod -R 0100 myScriptFolder`? Wouldn't that solve the security issues (provided no one uses your computer as root but you)?

Comment: Or can hackers from outside my local network somehow see the script text as it's executed, under certain circumstances?

Comment: This worked like a champ for me on my OSX box! Thanks so much for sharing the solution!

Comment: I tried this in a Dockerfile but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I got it in NodeJS (TypeScript) with the following @timebandit: 
const child = spawn("sudo", ["-S","-k","echo","Hello"])
    child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stdErr:', data.toString());
        child.stdin.write(password + '\n');
    });

    child.stdout.on('data', (data)=>{
        console.log('Received:', data.toString())
    })

Comment: works in ubuntu 2004. if you want to use it with sshpass you need escape it . like
sshpass -p mypassword ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ubuntu@127.0.0.5 'echo mypassword | sudo -S -k whoami'

Comment: `echo pass | sudo -S bash` does not work

Answer (score 70):

You can set the `s` bit for your script so that it does not need `sudo` and runs as root (and you do not need to write your root password in the script):

```
sudo chmod +s myscript
```

Comment: +1. This is way better (and more secure) than the other methods.

Comment: sticky bit is bad practice no ?

Comment: @kbdjockey - `+s` is the setuid bit. `+t` is the sticky bit.

Comment: See this Q/A that pertains to this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/440363/can-i-make-a-script-always-execute-as-root

Comment: Note that most OSes ignore this flag for interpreted script files. This does work nicely on binaries tho.

Answer (score 30):

```
echo -e "YOURPASSWORD\n" | sudo -S yourcommand
```

Comment: This doesn't work when I have an argument for my command. for example. `echo -e "YOURPASSWORD\n" | sudo -S "run -x"`. It says `sudo: run -x: command not found`. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: @Bhathiya simply don't use "quotes", for example:

echo -e "YOURPASSWORD\n" | sudo -S ls -l /root

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use the -A flag to sudo.  This runs a program to ask for the password.  Rather than ask, you could have a script that just spits out the password so the program can continue.

Answer (score -5):

```
# Make sure only root can run our script
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question.