# Sudo password with node

Tags: linux, node.js

I have built an UI with nwjs for a node app but It needs sudo password to execute a command. How can I interact with the console to enter a password given in a UI field? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955298/use-sudo-with-password-as-parameter).

If it's only one command then it's better to grant the user running node permissions to run the command without password. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password) from askbuntu should be applicable in a similar way on most linux distros.