# osx - sudo with password execute

Tags: macos, unix, command-line

Was trying to figure out how to execute a sudo command with the password as a parameter.

```
echo mypassword | sudo -S command
```

was using this reference [Use sudo with password as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955298/use-sudo-with-password-as-parameter)

However, on OS X it keeps say "sudo: incorrect password attempt" however that passwords is correct.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Just a tiny remark: this is a very bad idea. For example, if you type this into your command line, your password will be stored in your shell history. I have no idea what you're up to, but I think you're calling for trouble ;)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments already, what you're doing is a *very* bad idea because it leaves the password of an account laying around. Instead, if you need to run a specific command with sudo from a script, you could -- and you should -- define that *single* command for *one specific user* in such a way that its execution is allowed without having to type in the password.

So, you should edit `/etc/sudoers` to include an entry for *your specific user* for that *one, single, specific command* with the tag `NOPASSWD`:

```
youruser yourhostname = (root) NOPASSWD: /some/path/your/command
```

Or if you really don't feel like typing in the hostname of your computer, then go for:

```
youruser ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /some/path/your/command
```

That way you will possibly leak the ability of executing that *one, single command* as root instead of leaking your password and with it the possibility of running *any commands* as root.

Comment: Pretty sure that's NOT what they asked for.