# Include sudo password in linux executable file

Tags: linux

I have this code in a linux executable file to start atom from there:

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo atom
```

I wanted to include sudo password after that lines of code, so the program will run automatically.

Comment: [`sudo -S`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo).

Comment: That said, *don't do it this way!* (bad idea). Anyone who can read the file can read the sudo password. Instead run `visudo` and set the appropriate permissions for this user to run `sudo` without a password (you will probably have to add the user to the `wheel` (or lately the `sudo`) group as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use sudo with password as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955298/use-sudo-with-password-as-parameter)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't suggest hardcoding a password into your script as it carries a security risk.

Strictly speaking you can by doing:

```
echo "yourpassword" | sudo -S <command>
```

The `-S` flag will read the password from stdin.

There is another better way for you to allow password-less sudo commands by [modifying your sudoers file](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-running-sudo-command-without-a-password/).

Answer (score 0):

Why you not use sudoers?
Try running atom without password.

Edit `/etc/sudoers` via visudo:

```
visudo -f /etc/sudoers
```

Put new line and save:

```
youuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: atom
```

do not forget to replace `youuser`

Answer (score 0):

You dont need this. You need to use visudo:

```
sudo visudo
```

Then add line like this:

```
username ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh
```

And then run your script using `sudo script.sh` without password